# How can I install pdo_oci extension on Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: php, 14.10, oracle, extension

I have installed oci8 extension for php and it works. However for a project based on Laravel framework I need to use pdo-via-oci8 driver package. How can I install pdo_oci extension? (I have oracle instantclient 12. install and pecl download methods didn't work for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a complete purge of php installation I reinstalled php. Later following the steps described in here [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936091/how-to-install-oracle-instantclient-and-pdo-oci-on-ubuntu-machine) I could install pdo and pdo_oci as expected.